# Sharepoint 2007 => 2010 Migration issues on Visual Upgrade

Tags: 2010, 2007, migration

I've migrated one portal to a new farm, using the Detach Database method.

Everything went ok until I started testing.

Visual Upgrade didn't return any error but, when viewing list contents (AllItems.aspx) or displaying/editing items (DispItem.aspx/EditItem.aspx) the layouts are rendered incorrectly, all broken, and with some yellow/blue colors of 2007.

Anyone knows how to force update these forms?

Best regards!

Comment: Have you checked that these pages hasn't been modified using SharePoint designer? That would cause them to be stored in the content database and not getting updated implementation. Or they could be custom implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the UI version of the pages?

<strike>You can manually change the UI version from 3 to 4 in PowerShell. This is done in the same way as on an `SPWeb`, however the forms will be `SPFile` objects in the Forms library.</strike>

[`SPFile.UIVersion` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.uiversion.aspx)

[Manage Visual Upgrade (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607998.aspx)

## Edit:

To rectify this you have a few options:

> If the forms were custom and you'd like to retain that look:
>
> 1) Open each form in SPD and edit until the form is back to how you wanted it.
>
> If you'd like to revert to the default SharePoint forms:
>
> 2) In SPD, navigate to the site, click All Files, navigate to your list. If there is a blue/white exclamation point on the file icon you can right click and choose "Reset to site definition."
>
> 3) In the browser, navigate to the list > List Settings (in the ribbon under the List tab) > Form Settings > check "Use the default SharePoint form"

[image: Use the default SharePoint form]

Comment: I'll try it then, and then I'll give you some feedback on that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: SPFile.UIVersion is Read-Only and cannot be set.

Comment: Coincidentally, that option, in my installation, only has "Modify the existing InfoPath Form" listed on the options....

Comment: Don't know what to tell you to be honest. Have you compared the form code with the default form templates? You may be able to gain some insight that way.

Comment: I've just found "<View>" elements on the Lists definitions. It might be it. The "<Forms>" elements are pointing to the default forms, but there is a lot of custom markup in the "<Views>" elements.

Comment: `<View>`s are your list views. The forms are completely separate. You shouldn't be looking at the list definitions, you should be looking at the form page markup.

Comment: Yes... I really missed the list definition '<Forms>' which is instancing custom forms for these lists... That's why it wasn't migrating them.